# App working fine on simulator but shows multiple parse,semantic and arc errors on ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

[image]I am trying to run my app on ipad. I have already ran it on simulator and it works absolutely fine on on simulator with no error.But when I try to run it on ipad ,it shows multiple parse,arc and semantic errors and I am sure nothing is wrong in code as it used to work fine on devices too earlier but suddenly has started showing error.I have done the following things to resolve it but nothing worked:
1)quit xcode and start again
2)reboot ipad (clicking power button and home button together until apple icon appears)
3)cleaned(cmd+shif+k)
Is there any other way to fix it.Kindly give your suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also empty the derived data folder. Go to Xcode "Preferences" - "Location" - "Derived Data". Quit Xcode, empty derived data folder, and then restart Xcode. You might also want to reboot Mac if problem persists.

Comment: If you're still having problems, share some relevant code with a description of what the error was, and we might be able to help you. We obviously can't help you diagnose it on the basis of the information provided.

Comment: @Rob,emptying the derived data folder didn't work.